# Error while running the server in backend of my app?

Tags: node.js, express, mongodb-query

My server is showing an error which I can't figure out it?

can anyone help me to solve the error.[Showing an error in the router file can't able to figure out it .I'm trying to solve the error and run my server at the port but it's not going to happen form a while](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT4M0.png)

Comment: What is the code for the 'signup' you are importing? I'm guessing it is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object in the second argument of the post method.

You should pass a callback, that is a function.
You can declare the function and assign it to a variable:

```
var f_call = function (req, res) {
  //code
}
router.post(path, f_call);
```

Or add it to the post method directly:

```js
router.post(path, function(req, res) {
  //code
});
```

You can take a look in [express router](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like signup which you imported on line number 5 from `"../controller/Auth"` is not a function but an object, as mentioned by [tigremtm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22053185/tigremtm),  `express router` requires a function as a second parameter. Please check your signup at `"../controller/Auth"` and make it a function.